# Where do the trait bounds of `HashMap` actually come from?

Tags: rust, traits

As mentioned in the documentation of [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#examples) the key type `K` needs to implement `Hash`, `PartialEq`, and `Eq` which makes sense.

However, I would have expected that these trait bounds actually also show up somewhere in the documentation next to either the `struct` definition itself, or as trait bounds to the `impl` or so. But skimming over [the source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/std/collections/hash/map.rs.html) the only occurrence of e.q. `PartialEq` I can see is [this one](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/src/std/collections/hash/map.rs.html#1277), which isn't a trait bound, and I could spot these trait bounds in the whole source.

Out of sheer curiosity: Where do these trait bounds actually come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Eq` and `Hash` are on almost all methods, and `PartialEq` is a supertrait of `Eq`, so it is not needed to be specified explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, silly me. I was only looking for `PartialEq` because it is more easily searchable, and forgot that it can be implicit...